# Get Total of each item inside ForEach

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have two CoreData Entities with a one-to-many-relationship. My first problem was to display the total value of the subentity on the mainentity view, which I could solve with some help. The next problem I'm currently facing, is that I can't display the Total value of the main entity.

With the extension it is now possible to display the total value of each depot. But I also need the total value of all depots, which I'm not able to display.

```
extension Depot {
    func sumOfDepot() -> Double {
        aktienArray.map(\.a_purchValue).reduce(0, +)
    }
}

struct Portfolio: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Depot.d_name, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var depots: FetchedResults<Depot>
   
//DEPOT LIST
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                            Color.clear
                                .padding(.bottom, g.size.height / -200)
                            ForEach(depots) { depot in

                                ZStack {
                                    NavigationLink(destination: DepotDetail(depot: depot)) {
                                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
                                            HStack {
                                                VStack (alignment: .leading){
                                                    HStack (alignment: .bottom) {
                                                        
                                                    Text("Depot Value")
                                                
                                                    Text("\(depot.sumOfDepot() as NSNumber, formatter: formatter) €")  // SHOWS VALUE OF ONE DEPOT
                                                }
                                                Spacer()
                                                
                                            }
                                            Spacer()
                                            Spacer()
                                            Spacer()
                                        }
                                        .padding(.horizontal, g.size.width / 40)
                                        .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 4.7)
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).fill(Color.white))
                                    }.buttonStyle(FlatLinkStyle())
                                    
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: There is soooo much extra unneeded code. Look into derived properties they are the most efficient solution for this use case. Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @loremipsum I'm sorry for that. I've updated my code and I hope it's more clear now. The depot.sumOfDepot() displays the total value of the Many Relationship. Inside the foreach are multiple depots that are showing the total value of these sub entities. But now I don't know how to display the total value of all the depots outside of the foreach.

Comment: Look into derived attributes. If you search the "Developer" App for "derived attributes" and there is a CoreData session from a couple of years ago that shows a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

```
 Text("total: \(depots.map{ $0.sumOfDepot() }.reduce(0, +))")
```

to get the total value of all depots and display it in a `Text` view.